# The use of cookies and their security

Tags: php, security, cookies, encryption

### Background

As you all probably know: Cookies are small files which are stored on a user's computer. They are designed to hold a modest amount of data specific to a particular client and website, and can be accessed either by the web server or the client computer.

This knowledge made me wonder about the security of cookies and gave me a few questions

### My questions

- Are Cookies encrypted by default
- If they are not, how would I go about encrypting my cookies
- Above points aside, are cookies encrypted when I am using SSL

As I am a PHP developer above questions are all with the eye on PHP.

Comment: "Cookies are small files" — They aren't. That's a possible implementation detail of the mechanism the browser uses to store the data from cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Are Cookies encrypted by default

No, cookies are sent in the clear with whatever value you have set them to.

> - If they are not, how would I go about encrypting my cookies

Encrypting the key/value pairs or encrypting them for safe passage between the browser and the user?

For the latter, use TLS (same thing as SSL). For the former you should think about why you are encrypting them - there is usually no need to send them to the browser if you are encrypting them yourself.

> - Above points aside, are cookies encrypted when I am using SSL

Yes, they are encrypted during transit. However, unless you set the [Secure Flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag), the cookie will be transported unencrypted if the user goes to the `http://` version of your site.

e.g. if you set a cookie on `https://www.example.com` and then the user browses, or follows a link to `http://www.example.com` then the cookie will be sent in the clear. At attacker could also force the cookie to be leaked by MITM'ing a connection to another site then injecting `<img src="http://www.example.com/foo.bar" />` into the page causing the browser to connect to your site sending all cookies.

This is why it is advisable to always set the Secure Flag if you want a cookie to be HTTPS only.

Answer (score 0):

> Are Cookies encrypted by default

No.

> If they are not, how would I go about encrypting my cookies

If you want to hide the information from the user. Don't put it in a cookie in the first place. Keep it on the server. (And put a token that you can use to retrieve the right pot of information in the cookie).

If you want to hide the information from third party attackers. Use SSL.

> Above points aside, are cookies encrypted when I am using SSL

Everything transmitted between the server and the client (in both directions) is encrypted when you use SSL.